# Magento 2 Graphql Additional Product Image Values

Tags: magento2, graphql, magento2.4.5p1, magento-graphql, pwa-theme

Good afternoon all,

I am currently working with a custom frontend for Magento 2 that uses Graphql to grab product data:

Currently for the product image section we are getting back the following data attributes:

```
media_gallery {
   url
   position
   label
}
```

Is there a way that I can request any image roles that are associated with the images in the product gallery? The query would then be something like the following:

```
media_gallery {
   url
   position
   label
   role
}
```

I know this will require M2 backend module and any guidance on how to do this would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified outline of how you might go about this.

Step 1. Create a Custom Module
You'll first need to create a custom module. In the app/code directory, create a new directory for your module, say VendorName/ModuleName. In this new directory, create the following files:

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 2. Define a Schema Extension for GraphQL
In your module directory, create a file **etc/schema.graphqls**:

```
type ProductImage {
    role: [String] @doc(description: "Role of the image") @resolver(class: "\\VendorName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\MediaGalleryRole")
}
```

Step 3. Create a Resolver to Get the Media Roles for Image
Under **VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver**, create a new PHP class **MediaGalleryRole.php**:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class MediaGalleryRole implements ResolverInterface
{
    public const IMAGE_ROLES = ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'];

    private ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param Field $field
     * @param $context
     * @param ResolveInfo $info
     * @param array|null $value
     * @param array|null $args
     * @return array
     * @throws GraphQlNoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        if (!isset($value['model']) || !isset($value['file'])) {
            return [];
        }
        $sku = $value['model']->getData('sku');

        return $this->getImageRoles($sku, $value['file']);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $sku
     * @param string $fileName
     * @return array
     * @throws GraphQlNoSuchEntityException
     */
    private function getImageRoles(string $sku, string $fileName): array
    {
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException) {
            throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(__('No such product with sku %1', $sku));
        }

        $imageRoles = [];
        foreach (self::IMAGE_ROLES as $imageRole) {
            if ($product->getCustomAttribute($imageRole)?->getValue() === $fileName) {
                $imageRoles[] = $imageRole;
            }
        }

        return $imageRoles;
    }
}
```

*rebuild (bin/magento setup:di:compile)*

Example **query**:

```
query {
    products(search: "") {
        items {
            sku
            media_gallery {
                url
                label
                ... on ProductImage {
                    position
                    role
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: In the **MediaGalleryRole.php** resolver file, change the **IMAGE_ROLES** constant if other image file roles are provided

Comment: This looks brilliant, plenty for me to work with. I will look at applying and will come back with an update

Comment: This answer allowed me expand my solution with the image role information into my much larger query. I will mark this answer as correct, it is has been a while but my work queue was re-prioritised

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution, if what you are after are the types that you would select when either importing or manually adding images:

```
media_gallery_entries {
    file
    label
    types
}
```

"Types" returns an Array of image types. It can have the following values: image, small_image, thumbnail.